# RecyclerView need to scroll along the activity

Tags: android

I have a situation like this

```
<Header> 
 <RecylerView>
<Header> 
 <RecylerView>
```

Everything works fine - here is one thing I want to achieve.

When I scroll on the page, I need to scroll it as one list.
But now as there are two list I can scroll inside the recycler view.

Comment: Why don't you use one `RecyclerView` and make you adapter handle the views depending on whether it's a header or a data item?
you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26245463/886001) to handle different view types

Comment: Its complex inside as I have drag and drop inside each Recycle view. And drag and drop is recycle view dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use 2 `RecyclerViews`, you should use `NestedScrollView` as parent view, also add `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` to both the `RecyclerViews` and they will scroll along the page as a single list:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
  <Header> 
  <RecylerView
   android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"   <-- P.S this tag is very important or else each recyclerview will scroll within them selves. 
   />
  <Header> 
  <RecylerView
   android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Glad to know :)