# RecyclerView with Glide images needs to scroll along with the activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I have one activity that includes some textviews and one recyclerView that has images displayed with Glide. I had a problem that recyclerview has its own scroller that I don't need.

Then I added this: android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" to RecyclerView xml

according to [RecyclerView need to scroll along the activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46732064/recyclerview-need-to-scroll-along-the-activity)

and now recyclerview is scrolling along with activity, but now there is another problem. Not all images are visible. It looks like that RecyclerView does not know what is the size of all images inside it while it is inflating. I am using Glide for displaying images, and image item has fixed size 250dp.

If I remove nestedScrollingEnabled attribute, then all images are visible but I need to scroll inside that recyclerView.

this is my recyclerview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_prikazi_vest"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin1"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin1"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        tools:context="myapp.app.news">

----------------here are some textviews----------------------


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_images"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

this is setting I use for Glide

```
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
        .centerCrop()
        .placeholder(R.drawable.image1)
        .error(R.drawable.image2)
        .priority(Priority.HIGH);
```

Update:

to have smooth scroll please use this inside recyclerview

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
android:isScrollContainer="false"
```

Comment: Could you show me your view holder xml?

Comment: I have edited question

Comment: Could you show me the xml of item? I mean the xml inflate(R.layout.blalba) <-this one.

Comment: Can you try removing `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` to `Relative Layout` and also don't forget to remove all constraint attributes in your xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Change `ScrollView` to `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView`, and remove `android:nestedScrollingEnabled` attribute. NestedScrollView is layout that can contains scrollable children.

---

One option is change `centerCrop()` to `fitCenter()`.

```
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
    .fitCenter()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.image1)
    .error(R.drawable.image2)
    .priority(Priority.HIGH);
```

Details about glide option:
https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Transformations

[image: center crop] [image: fit center]

Details about centerCrop, fitCenter
https://robots.thoughtbot.com/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide

Comment: It changed the appearance of an image, but still, not all images are displayed. Only 3 images are visible. When I turn scrolling on, I can see all images, but I need to scroll them inside this activity scroller which is very confusing to the user.

Comment: Switching to NestedScrollView solved the problem, then I just needed to allow vertical slider and that is all. Thanks

Comment: There is only one more problem with scrolling. It is smooth while I am going to bottom, and then when I go up, it is not smooth and it does not continue scrolling when I swipe my finger but stops at the moment I lift my finger.